# React not re-rendering on state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently rendering a page with a bunch of Pokemon laid out in separate "cards". Each Pokemon can be favorited and unfavorited depending on the state, and favoriting the Pokemon will turn the card pink while unfavoriting the Pokemon will turn it back to its standard grey color.

I'd like to have the page or Pokemon card re-render to its proper color and have its proper favorite or unfavoriting method right after clicking the button, but currently I have to refresh the page in order for this to happen. Currently, my component Pokemon is being rendered by my component Dashboard, where Dashboard will map out 30 different Pokemon components and lay them out in a grid-like fashion. So I'm wondering if this is feasible? Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import './Pokemon.css';
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';
import 'reactjs-popup/dist/index.css';
import UserContext from '../../context/userContext';
import { array } from 'prop-types';

import axios from 'axios';


function Pokemon(props) { // Have app.js pass in props of the jsons to here? Then render their names and pictures, and prepare if click
  const [isFav, setIsFav] = useState();
  const { userData, setUserData } = useContext(UserContext); // use userData.user.favPokemon to access the favorite pokemon
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [putArr, setPutArr] = useState([...userData.user.favPokemon]);
  // Can use userData.user.favPokemon.find(props.pokemon.name) to search for the pokemon. If found (i.e. not undefined)
  // then render it differently.


  useEffect(() => {
    const found = (element) => element === props.pokemon.name;
    const isFound = (userData.user.favPokemon).some(found);
    setIsFav(isFound);
    if (isFound) {
      const index = userData.user.favPokemon.indexOf(props.pokemon.name);
      const removedFav = putArr;
      removedFav.splice(index, 1);

      setPutArr(removedFav); // array we will be PATCH'ing when we want to unfavorite a pokemon (array - current pokemon)
      // putArr.splice(index, 1); 
    }
    else {
      setPutArr(putArr.concat(props.pokemon.name)); // array we will be PATCH'ing when we want to favorite a pokemon (array + current pokemon)
      // putArr.push(props.pokemon.name) 
    }
  }, [isFav])

  const id = userData.user.id;
  const favOrUnfav = async (e) => { // Patch method to favorite or unfavorite a pokemon
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      console.log(putArr);
      const updateUser = {id, putArr};
      await axios.patch("http://localhost:5000/users/favorite", updateUser);
    } catch(err) {
      err.response.data.msg && setError(err.response.data.msg)
    }
    setIsFav(!isFav);
  };
    
  const pokeFacts = {
    imageUrl: props.pokemon.sprites.front_default,
    name: props.pokemon.name,
    ability: props.pokemon.abilities[0].ability.name,
    numberMoves: props.pokemon.moves.length,
    type: props.pokemon.types,
    stats: props.pokemon.stats
  }

  return (
    isFav === true ? 
    <div className="Pokemon-card-fav">
      <Popup trigger={<div><img className="Pokemon-card-image" src={pokeFacts.imageUrl} alt="Picture of a pokemon"></img>
      {pokeFacts.name} <button className="favButton" onClick={(e) => {favOrUnfav(e); console.log(isFav)}}>UnFavorite</button></div>} modal>
        <div>
          <p><b>Name</b>: {pokeFacts.name}</p>
          <p><b>Ability</b>: {pokeFacts.ability}</p>
          <p><b>Number of Possible Moves</b>: {pokeFacts.numberMoves}</p>
          <p><b>Type</b>: {pokeFacts.type.map((index) => (index.type.name) + " ")}</p>
          <p><b>Base Stats</b>: {pokeFacts.stats.map((index) => (index.stat.name) + ": " + (index.base_stat) + " ")}</p>
        </div>
      </Popup>
    </div>
    :
    <div className="Pokemon-card">
      <Popup trigger={<div><img className="Pokemon-card-image" src={pokeFacts.imageUrl} alt="Picture of a pokemon"></img>
      {pokeFacts.name} <button className="favButton" onClick={(e) => {favOrUnfav(e); console.log(isFav)}}>Favorite</button></div>} modal>
        <div>
          <p><b>Name</b>: {pokeFacts.name}</p>
          <p><b>Ability</b>: {pokeFacts.ability}</p>
          <p><b>Number of Possible Moves</b>: {pokeFacts.numberMoves}</p>
          <p><b>Type</b>: {pokeFacts.type.map((index) => (index.type.name) + " ")}</p>
          <p><b>Base Stats</b>: {pokeFacts.stats.map((index) => (index.stat.name) + ": " + (index.base_stat) + " ")}</p>
        </div>
      </Popup>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pokemon;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it actually, just have to have an empty array in the useEffect instead of having [isFav]! I think this makes sense since you're going to want to do that every time the component is mounted, which is what the [] will do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can render Pokemon component with Pokemon props without http request in the component.

I mean you should do request in parent component andpass props to Pokemon component. You can do request after click by button in parent component and pass props to Pokemon component, so your component will be re-render.

You can create useCallback function which do your Pokemon !favorite in Parent component and pass to Pokemon so that you can use in for change favorite status.

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is that `favOrUnfav` is not resolving and hence `setIsFav` is not executing.

What I would suggest is to call the `.then` method once it has completed and then set state.

```js
  const favOrUnfav = async (e) => { // Patch method to favorite or unfavorite a pokemon
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      console.log(putArr);
      const updateUser = {id, putArr};
      await axios.patch("http://localhost:5000/users/favorite", updateUser).then(() => {
          setIsFav(!isFav);
      });
    } catch(err) {
      err.response.data.msg && setError(err.response.data.msg)
    }
  };
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, it operates the same way